# apache2.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, systemd, apache2, debian-stretch

I can't restart my apache server on debian 9.

I tried reinstall :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge apache2 && sudo apt-get install apache2
```

but no change...

```
Job for apache2.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
```

systemctl status apache2.service

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources)
```

journalctl -xeu apache2.service
(I set loglevel to debug mod)

```
Sep 05 11:45:44 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Sep 05 11:50:26 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Changed dead -> failed
Sep 05 11:50:27 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Trying to enqueue job apache2.service/stop/replace
Sep 05 11:50:27 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Installed new job apache2.service/stop as 1415
Sep 05 11:50:27 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Enqueued job apache2.service/stop as 1415
Sep 05 11:50:27 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Job apache2.service/stop finished, result=done
Sep 05 11:50:27 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Changed dead -> failed
Sep 05 11:50:30 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Sep 05 11:50:30 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 05 11:50:30 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Can you find any useful logging in _/var/log/messages_ or other log files, e.g. **dmesg**?

Comment: no log about apache2 when i try start... /var/log/apache2/error.log have only failed connexion messages from client trying to connect on website...

Comment: If your error.log file gets new log messages, then Apache is running. Can you confirm with **ss -lnt**?

Comment: interesting ! in fact I have new log like : `2018/09/05 13:19:28 [error] 933#933: *1762 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:88/favicon.ico", host: "mywebsite.com"
`

Comment: So... can you confirm Apache is running? Do you have a listener on port 88 when you run **ss -lnt**? Also please include the configuration file as you're obviously not using the default config, given you're connecting on port 88.

Comment: but I have a nginx on port 80 with rerouting on apache on port 88, it's maybe for that ... `ps -aux | grep apache` have nothing.

Comment: ss -int see only on port 80 (ngnix)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the default Apache configuration, it tries to listen on port 80 which is already in use by nginx. Change your Apache configuration to listen on port 88 instead.

```
listen 88
```

Comment: I have the same error with my conf or default conf, or default conf + modify the port to 88 : `apache2.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory`

Comment: Very late reply but... can you share your Apache configuration files? There must be something wrong in there. A reinstall not always removes all config files.

Comment: late, I have format my disk and now all works ^^

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check if there is an environment file. in Debian based systems this would be found in `/etc/default/$file` (not sure what actual file name is) on CentOS/RHEL based systems it would be found in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd...`

I'm *adding this answer since I had this issue and a  format is not an option... So for whoever may stumble across this I had to figure it out myself. The giveaway was the startup script.

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service | grep -i environment  

EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd
```